# Copy subsection of a multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

In Processing (java based language) I can do this;

```
int [][] a = new int[3][2];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  a[i][0] = i;
  a[i][1] = i+3;
}
int [] b = a[2];
```

b is a one dimensional array with the values 2 and 5.  It takes the array in row 2 of array a.

matlab syntax would be

```
b = a(3,:);
```

Is there any equivalent for c#?  I can't seem to find anything but seems like a fairly useful and obvious feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# has [multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4), but it also has arrays of arrays (also called [*jagged* arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)). The second form is what you are after:

```
// This is a jagged array. It has 3 rows, each of which is an int[] in its own right.
// Each row can also have a different number of elements from all the others, so if
// a[i][N] is valid for some i and N, a[x][N] is not necessarily valid for other x != i
var a = new int[3][];

// To populate the array you need to explicitly create an instance for each sub-array
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
      a[i] = new[] { i, i + 3 };
}

// And now this is possible:
var b = a[2];
```

If you have a multidimensional array at hand, you will need to do the copying manually.

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong.  When making the jagged array to begin with I specified both sizes in the jagged array, which produced a compiler error.  I am used to being able to specify both.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

C# distinguishes between *jagged arrays* (`[][]`) and *multidimensional arrays* (`[,]`):

**Jagged Arrays:**

This should be possible; every array element is just an array itself.

**Multidimensional Arrays:**

Here, you will have to do the copying yourself, element by element.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers: if you really want a copy, i.e. you don't want `b[0] = 42;` to change `a[2][0];`, then do this:

```
int [] b = (int[])a[2].Clone();
```